# Getting results of a query with multiple rows as result into a single row

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, tuples

Is there anyway to get mysql query results as

```
(id,result1,[result21,result22, result23])
```

I am trying to retrieve results where the third column is a timestamp and it corresponds to same ids.

For e.g. I am getting results as

```
(21,29383)
(21,23988)
(22,23455)
(22,34564)
```

I want results as

```
(21,(29383,23988))
(21,(223455,34564))
```

Comment: can you post some sample data?

Comment: See the `GROUP_CONCAT()` aggregation function.

Comment: can you post which mysql module you're using and the code you're using to get the results?

Comment: Hi fthiella. I have posted sample data. That is the format that I am looing for. I have to convert a list of tuples to a maybe even a dictionary with with a tuple of values for a key. Also, in the list of tuples  - the first row is getting repeated over multiple rows. THis is what I want to group and get the results in the form - (21,(29383,23988))

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with MySQL, but if you get your results as Python tuples, you can manipulate the data structures on the Python side. One possible way could be:

```
from collections import defaultdict

results = [
    (21,29383),
    (21,23988),
    (22,23455),
    (22,34564)
]

d = defaultdict(list)

for your_id, result in results:
    d[your_id].append(result)

results_as_tuples = tuple(
    sorted([
        (your_id, tuple(results)) for your_id, results in d.iteritems()
    ])
)

print results_as_tuples # --> ((21, (29383, 23988)), (22, (23455, 34564)))
```

Comment: Hi. I did try this:
Got the error:

for your_id, result in results:
"Value error: Too many values to unpack". But then iteritems() was used towards this right?

Comment: @SumitSaurav: The error you are getting means that your tuples consist of more than two entries. In your example data, however, each tuple consists of two entries only, so this is what my code example works for. groupby() could be an option, yes.

Comment: Hi Peter. I've put my code, and the output I desire. Maybe it will make it much clearer. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @SumitSaurav Please put your additional code in your question but not in my answer.